# How to save data from API to state in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I save my object that is fetched from API in state in such a way that after page refresh it should be still available.How to save fetched data from API to state with parameter name?

As i don't want to save object in local storage or session storage.

This can be helpful in such a way that before fetching to the same API it will check if the object  is already there then no fetching is required for  that API

Suppose mine API look like `https://example.com/new/${numberID}/staff`

When first time API is executed for the {numberID} => 12ab1 parameter it should store the result for that {numberID} in state now when {numberID}=> 13ab2 parameter is updated again it should store in new state in such a way

Now {numberID} => 12ab1 parameter called again rather fetching from API it should fetch details from state. this will save my API re- hitting

Is this possible using react-hooks?

Comment: data stored in the state is set to blank or default value you set after each refresh

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

State is maintained for the lifetime of the application. When you refresh the page, you are destroying the current instance of the application and creating a new one, therefore state can not be persisted.

The only way to persist data across a refresh is to use third party software or things like browser storage.

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorage API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

You can put your data in localStorage and get it from there if you need it. For example

```
          if (!localStorage.getItem('data')) {
              axios.get(`https://example.com/new/${numberID}/staff`)
                  dispatch({
                      type: "FETCHSUCCESS",
                      payload: response.data
                  });
                  localStorage.setItem('data', response.data);
              })
              .catch(error => {
                  dispatch({
                      type: "FETCHFAILURE"
                  });
              });
          }
```